# RN release APK versionCode, api level, target, etc mismatch when upload to play console

Tags: android, react-native

I'm building a new apps with react-native and upload it to play console and it always have the same version with my config.
Then we have to change some code and include some new library that increase the size almost 40mb.
I already search how to compress the size and some people recommend to set
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true
and it works, our app size become half.
But when we upload it, the versionCode become mismatch.
this is my config :

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myApps"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 4
        versionName "0.0.4"
        missingDimensionStrategy "react-native-camera", "general"
    }
```

this is the result, notice the different :
[above new, below old](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WFMq.png)

anyone have any idea whats going on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React native has only one CPU architecture at a time you are enabling all the Architecture so your current APK has all the Architecture so it will increase your app size. If you want to see details of your app then Analyze your apk in android studio 
for more about Architecture see this issue in react-native [github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24154)

Comment: thanks, with ur hint I dig more into cpu architecture and I realize that defaultConfig only apply to universal apk, not for split cpu. Thank you